# Capturing Timecode Using an Apogee Duet

Tags: timecode

This may not be possible, but here it goes...

I'm curious if I can capture timecode out of a DV camera, using a BNC Male to XLR Male converter cable, into an Apogee Duet.

I will be recording an interview using a Sennheiser ME 66 on a boom through an Apogee Duet and into Logic Pro. Not the most ideal setup, but it's what I have to work with.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to do, but unless you are recording on film, it is probably much, much easier just to marker sync.

If your camera has an onboard mic, make sure it's on. If it doesn't, see if you can't get some mic on it (doesn't matter what it is - just has to capture audio). Then when you pull the footage in during post, match up the transients of your marker on each take. Just make sure you're in the same frame rate!!! (Logic should be set to record in 48k!)

If you don't have a way to get audio into the camera, you can still sync. Just line up the marker close frame with the transient of the audio. Using a frame bump quick key and scrub wheel, this should be a fairly quick process.

Then there is always the program "Plural Eyes" which pretty much does the above automatically (provided you have audio on the camera).

TC striping (as you described above - TV to audio track) really only works well if you have a clock you can send it back into. FCP only reads TC metadata, and unless you are going to re-record your tracks onto a machine with a TC input (DAT, XDCam, etc... or another computer with a TC input) it will just be too much of a headache on your part.

After all this is said, is there a reason you don't just record audio to the camera? It's not the best option in most situations, but this, being an interview, should really need much level riding, just boom movement (if even that). Then sync won't be an issue.

Comment: Thanks Colin. I think I will just use a slate to sync. I've just always been curious if I could capture TC for easier syncing with my setup. But, I agree and think it may be more of a hassle. The client had a bad experience the last time they recorded audio to their camera. Not exactly sure why, but I'm not going to question it... I can use the gig!

Comment: Yeah.  What Colin Said.  There's no direct TC input on the duet anyways, and in the end, a TC stripped track in Final Cut isn't as useful as one in Avid (editing).  Stick with the slates and/or plural eyes.  It'll be much easier to deal with.

Comment: Great. Thanks again for both of your inputs!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not.

What do you need the audio TC for?

Audio TC is a rather loud source.  If you have a line level in on the duet, then you should be ok.  The only potential problem is bleed from the audio channel that you have your boom mic going into and the audio channel with the TC.

-greg-

Comment: Thanks Greg. Sorry, I'm not familiar with "audio" TC. I'm just trying to get the TC generated from a DV camera into something that I can see in FCP to help sync the audio I'm recording separately. Are you saying if I record the TC using the work-flow mentioned above that I will have to convert it to something I can see in FCP?

Regarding bleeding: The Duet has 2 separate channels and levels can be adjusted on each channel. So hopefully bleeding won't be an issue.